# Can you please find this paper "Idealistic exponents of singularity" by H. Hironaka,1977, from journal "Algebraic Geometry"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I couldn't find the research paper entitled `Idealistic exponents of singularity` by the author H. Hironaka published in the journal `Algebraic Geometry`, 1977 .

Can you please help me finding this ?

Thanks

Comment: This was not published in a journal but in this book https://www.worldcat.org/title/algebraic-geometry-the-johns-hopkins-centennial-lectures-supplement-to-the-american-journal-of-mathematics/oclc/3402740 Maybe your university library could get it by interlibrary loan.

Comment: @AnginaSeng, Can you please tell me the book name ?

Comment: All the bibliographic information I know is in that link.